# How to convert data to 10-point range scale in Python?

Tags: python

The disease severity levels in plants is given within the range 0 (no disease) to 10 (severe disease). For example, some 12 plants have their disease levels as:

(1.7, 3.7, 5.3, 7.3, 2.3, 3.7, 5.7, 7.3, 1, 4, 5.7, 6.7)

Using another method the same plants are assigned the following values:

(186.6377, 207.7993, 179.8552, 225.7226, 212.0066, 215.8321, 218.337, 199.9707, 179.5959, 203.2275, 212.2286, 212.5489)

How can I convert the second set of values to the 0 to 10 scale in order to compare the values assigned to each plant?
The closest I have seen is [the scale function. Unfortunately, it deals with ranges of 0 to 1](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html)

Comment: You talk about having a 0-10 scale, but show data completely outside that range.  Maybe if you gave an example of how would expect this program to convert those values?

Comment: Multiply the result of `range 0 to 1` with 10?

Comment: What about something like `[10*x/max(ds) for x in ds]` where `ds` is disease severity data?

Comment: @Scott, the first set has values within the scale while the second set has the values I wish to convert to within the 0-10 scale.

Comment: @Gathide: OK, but you have given no indication of how you want that conversion to go, regardless of how it is implemented.  For example: what should 186.6377 get mapped to?

Comment: @ScottHunter, my question is how I can convert my values to values within the 0 to 10 scale. For instance using your e.g. how can I convert 186.6377 to a value within 0 to 10. And the aim is to be in a position to compare the two sets of values. Is it clear now?

Comment: @Moinuddin, rather than multiply uniformly with 10, can it be proportional to the value of each element in set 2? None of these values is a max (10) or a min (0), but should be within the range.

Comment: @Gathide: Not clear at all; there are (literally) an infinite number of ways to map an arbitrary set of values into a 0-10 range.

Comment: The upshot so far seems that I should provide the **max/min** of the second set! I will see how to get that using the method that provided the values and update the question.

Answer (score 4):

You could make a conversion function:

```
def convert(x,a,b,c=0,d=1):
    """converts values in the range [a,b] to values in the range [c,d]"""
    return c + float(x-a)*float(d-c)/(b-a)
```

For example:

```
>>> convert(215.8321,170,230,0,10)
7.638683333333333
```

(replace `170` and `230` by the min/max values, which are not given in your problem description).

Comment: The second set of values has no known min nor max values.

Comment: @Gathide In that case, I don't see how a meaningful answer is even possible, although assuming that they are uniformly distributed, an unbiased estimator for the max is the (n+1)/n * (sample max) where `n` is the sample size, and similarly for the min. But without some assumptions, you are in danger of converting meaningful apples into meaningless oranges.

Comment: Ok. That simply implies I should strive to get the maximum and minimum possible values corresponding to the second set before thinking of the conversion I wanted?

Comment: @Gathide Ideally, yes. Numbers need a context to make sense, so unless you have a context for the second set of numbers it is hard to say much. On the other hand, for an equation of a line you only need two values. If there were two values in the second set for which you independently knew the corresponding values in the range 0-10, that would be enough.