# Convert log10-Data to a 1-11 scale

Tags: math, scale, logarithm

I want to convert my data to a 1-11 scale. At first, I took the raw data and converted them with the following formula, which I took from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40792563/7253302):

```
scale_min + float(x-data_min)*float(scale_max-scale_min)/(data_max-data_min)
```

However, since my data has extreme outliers, this makes the differences in most of the data impossible to see.
I thought about taking the log10 of the data and then converting those values to my 1-11 scale, however, the above formula does not work with negative values, which can occur with log10.
Is there any other way of mapping log10 values to a 1-11 scale? Or any other way of mapping data with extreme outliers to a 1-11 scale in a way which makes differences in smaller values perceivable, while not losing any of the information?

An example for my values would be

```
[0.1, 10, 300, 500000]
```

Comment: Why do you say "the above formula doesn't work with negative values"? It should. it's a simple affine function of `x` and shouldn't care whether `x` is negative or positive.

Comment: @Stef Oh no, you're right... I made an error in my reasoning...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see a reason why your formula shouldn't work with negative numbers. It is a simple affine function.

Example in python:

```py
from math import log10

data = [0.1, 10, 300, 500000]

logdata = [log10(x) for x in data]

a = min(logdata)
b = max(logdata)

data1_11 = [1 + (y - a) * 10 / (b - a) for y in logdata]

print(data1_11)
# [1.0, 4.0, 6.2, 11.0]
```